# load shared file on a netword with webkitbrowser - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit

I want to load an **HTML file that is shared in the network** with **webkitbrowser** in winform C#. for examle:

file:///10.10.10.10/files/index.html

I Also tried: file://///10.10.10.10//files//index.html

webkitbrowser doesnt load html file. in local, there is no problem. i use this url: file:///c://index.html

**WinAPP, C# , visual Studio 2010**

thanks in advance